# JSON DECODE using PHP

Tags: php, json, decode

I am doing some JSON decodes - I followed this tutorial well explained - [How To Parse JSON With PHP](http://webtutsdepot.com/2009/08/31/how-to-read-json-data-with-php/)

and the PHP code, I used

```
 <?php
 $string='{"person":[
            {
                "name":{"first":"John","last":"Adams"},
                "age":"40"
            },
            {
                "name":{"first":"Thomas","last":"Jefferson"},
                "age":"35"
            }
         ]}';

$json_a=json_decode($string,true);

$json_o=json_decode($string);


// array method
foreach($json_a[person] as $p)
{
echo '

Name: '.$p[name][first].' '.$p[name][last].'

Age: '.$p[age].'

';

}




// object method
foreach($json_o->person as $p)
{
echo '

<br/> Name: '.$p->name->first.' '.$p->name->last.'

Age: '.$p->age.'

';
}


 ?>
```

It is working correctly... But my concern I need only details of Thomas' last name and age. I need to handle this to extract only certain features, not all the objects.

Comment: That has little to do with JSON, nor with `decode`. It is a matter of retrieving parts of a PHP data structure. Also, don't name your variables `json_a` or `json_o`, because they are not JSON. Your `$string` is the only JSON string out there.

Comment: So is your question really : *why don't I put an `if ($p->name->first === 'Thomas') {` in my loop?*

Comment: Thank you. I have a JSON file - [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mledoze/countries/master/countries.json]  - I just need to retrieve only currency of a country.. not fully.. Do you say I need to use 'if ()'

Comment: Yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given [this JSON](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mledoze/countries/master/countries.json), you can get the currency of a country as follows:

```
function getCurrencyFor($arr, $findCountry) {
    foreach($arr as $country) {
        if ($country->name->common == $findCountry) {
            $currency = $country->currency[0];
            break;
        }
    }
    return $currency;
}

$json = file_get_contents("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mledoze/countries/master/countries.json");
$arr = json_decode($json);
// Call our function to extract the currency for Angola:
$currency = getCurrencyFor($arr, "Angola");

echo "Angola has $currency as currency";
```

Comment: Thank you, @trincot. '$currency = getCurrencyFor($arr, "Afghanistan");' I replaced Angola to Afghanistan. Still it shows the same.. 'AWG as currency' Do you think I must change the code somewhere..

Comment: There was a mistake in the code. The `if` should of course have `==` instead of `=`. Stupid of me.

Comment: I tried to get function getCurrencyFor($arr, $findCountry) // function for get currency
{
    foreach (array($currency, $capital) as &$country) {
        if ($country->name->common == $findCountry) {
   array 
            $currency = $country->currency[0];
   $capital = $country->capital;
            break;
        }
    }
return $currency;
}
$json     = file_get_contents("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mledoze/countries/master/countries.json");
$arr      = json_decode($json);
// Call our function to extract the currency for Angola:
$currency = getCurrencyFor($arr, "Aruba");

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you are saying.

Comment: I used `foreach (array($currency, $capital) as &$country) {` to get values of two objects currency and capital, some reason the code does not work. Here is the sandbox http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a294303daf35f947e043bea83bdf20f9184a14ba thank you

Comment: No, that wont work. Your input is `$arr`, so if you leave that out, you are lost. You should leave the `foreach` part as it was. Also, why do you use the `&` before `$country`: it serves no purpose in your case? If you want to get the capital, then think about what else you want to get. Maybe you want to get all attributes of a country, so then just return the country, and grab what you need outside of the function. Of course, the function name "getCurrencyFor" makes no sense anymore if you make changes like this.

Comment: `&` yes it does not make any sense for me. I understand that `$arr` - helps to locate the country and return the value of `&currency ` from array value. Perhaps I need one more value of the object like capital, I thought to use array in foreach...

Comment: thank you. Let me know if you have any suggestions @trincot

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give the JSON data that you provided the link to, this should return the currency value for the given country:

```
$country_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mledoze/countries/master/countries.json"), TRUE);

function get_currency($name) {
    global $country_data;

    $name = strtolower($name);
    $output = reset(array_filter($country_data, function ($value, $key) use($name) {
        if(strtolower($value['name']['common']) === $name || strtolower($value['name']['official']) === $name) {
            return true;
        }
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH))['currency'];
    return ($output) ? $output : array();
}

/* Return same results */

echo "<pre>";
print_r(get_currency("Islamic Republic of Afghanistan"));
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r(get_currency("Afghanistan"));
echo "</pre>";
```

**NOTE:** The above function is case-insensitive. If you need case sensitivity supported, remove the `strtolower()` function references.

**EDIT:**

- Corrected a bug in the snippet.

**EDIT 2:**

- Returns an array of currencies if the country name is found or an empty array `array()` if the country cannot be found.
- The name passed into `get_currency()` is now checked against the `common` name and the `official` name. Passing either will return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually  Thomas is the first name not last name
try this code..

print "names:", ",".join(x["last"] for x in obj if x["first"] == "Thomas")

Comment: now try again just put here  join(x["last"]  what you want